# Rails 5 file naming convention for rendering AJAX request results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Let's assume there's a model called **City** and we make a search form to search through the names of available cities in the model.

**Is it necessary to name the partial that will be rendered as result of AJAX request to be named as `_city.html.erb` only?** If so, why? And if not, then how can we name the file something else and use that?  Maybe one needs to use multiple AJAX situations for a model, for example adding a city, search, etc., so they will all render the same partial, which may not be what the developer desires.

I tried different names but nothing worked except that.
My search route is `/cities_search` using `GET` method mapped to `cities#search`.
My JS file name is `search.js.erb`.

In index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag cities_search_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, required: true %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil%>
<% end %>
Search:
<div id="search-results">

</div>
```

JS code:

```
$("#search-results").empty();
<% if @foundcities %>
    $("#search-results").append("<%= j render @foundcities %>");
<% else %>
    $("#search-results").append("No city found");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please provide your view and js code

Comment: It depends on your action name

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun Added

Comment: @Deepak I tried that, I named the file _search.html.erb, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= j render @foundcities %>` this is the part that is making it necessary to name the partial specifically. By just calling `render` on a collection of objects, you are using the default naming scheme for that object (which uses the class name). if you want something different, then you try using a different `render` eg

```
render :partial => 'my_partial_name', :locals => {:found_cities => @foundcities}
```

Note that you'll need to refer to the local variable: `found_cities` in your partial instead of the global `@foundcities`

(also it's a convention in rails to prefer `snake_case` over `jammedtogetherwordscase`) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried your method, it works but if I write anything else in the file like an IF condition or styling, nothing appears(I was able to do it in my original code though, I had an IF condition as well as styling too, like this: `<% if @foundcities %><span class="tag tag-primary"><%=  @foundcities.name %></span>
<% end %>`)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem with that... (also it probably counts as a new question... the original problem of not being able to change the partial is fixed). Can you create a new question based around this, and include a code example etc? You can refer back to this question so they're connected. Also, if you post the link to the new question here then I'll be notified and can go look :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'll notify you whenever I make the new question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options with render.  In this case, you want:

```
render :partial => 'partial_name', :collection => @foundcities
```

Then the partial file would be named "_partial_name.html.erb".  In the js.erb file, you'd do this sort of thing:

```
<% result = @foundcities ? render(:partial => 'partial_name', :collection => @foundcities) : "No city found" %>
$("#search-results").html("<%= j result %>");
```

Comment: I tried this in my JS- `$("#search-results").append("<%= render :partial => 'cities/search', :collection => @foundcities %>");` On terminal it does tell that the partial got rendered but nothing gets displayed. I removed the `:collection` attribute, I was able to print using `<%= @foundcities.name%>` but I wasn't able to write anything else in the file like an if condition or styling.

Comment: In javascript/jquery, the append function will need an escaped string.   Added to the answer...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it still isn't working. I'll make a new question instead.